# How to egrep the month from the date?

Tags: regex, date, unix

I want to ask how I can use `egrep` to extract only the month section of a date in the form of

```
mm/dd/yyyy at hh:mm:ss
```

I've tried the *positive lookbehind assertion* but it didn't seem to work. The context of this code is: I'm looking at multiple files and gathering the dates from each of the files into `timestamp.txt`. In the original files, all the dates are located after `TimeStamp:`(note space after colon)

I'm not too great with regular expressions so I know I'm missing the expression to block out the `/` after the first two digits as well. If anybody can help me with that, that would be awesome :D

```
egrep "(?<=TimeStamp:\s)" $CURFILE | sort >> ../timestamp.txt
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happened on the Mayflower. Then even messed up the order in dates. i.e d/m/y in the UK, m/d/y in the US. I hope they enjoyed the tea in Boston!!

Comment: Please provide an example of input.

Comment: Why you try to do a lookbehind? `TimeStamp:\s(\d{2})\/\d{2}\/\d{4}` how about this? it works in PCRE

Comment: @revo I tried look behind in order to get the month. I tried your solution. Didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Basilevs The input file is kind of like an email. The file is stored in the variable $CURFILE and my script uses egrep to find the month from that file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible with egrep but it is with perl

```
echo "TimeStamp: 12/10/2012"| perl -n -e 'print $1f m#: (..)/#'
```

Here's an other way of doing this

```
  echo "TimeStamp: 12/10/2012"| awk -F/ '{print $1}' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm only a beginner at programming in Unix. Do you mind providing me a solution that uses mostly basic commands?

Comment: sorry Basilevs I never use ``sed``, added examples for ``cut`` and ``awk``

Comment: aww! Really close! I tried the cut option but got the days instead. Switched out the 2 for a 1 but got TimeStamp: mm

Comment: @Vorsprung, cascade cuts :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "TimeStamp: 12/10/2012"| grep TimeStamp: | cut -d ' ' -f 2 |cut -d '/' -f 1
```

The code is untested and might have argument escaping problems.

The idea is to first split the input by space (or colon) and then by slash. If there are more spaces in the line you might need to manipulate -f values or add more splits.

Comment: @Vorsprung, you removed similar proposal, so I've revived and updated it.